# CodeIgniter - Get next record from an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I get all data from a table to a array :

```
$records = $this->Misc->getAll('table');
```

Next I made a loop

```
foreach ($records as $key => $record) {     
    // here i want to update a column in the fist
    // row with a value from the second row
    $this->Misc->update($record->id; $value_of_a_column_from_the_next_row);
}
```

How can I do this?
Thanks

Comment: This is unusual, what are you really trying to do? I could give you a "solution" but I'm in doubt that it will really solve your problem.

Comment: Do you only want to update the first record or do you want to shift the values from *all* records? More context would be helpful.

Comment: First row 'a1','a2','a3',' null ','a4' ..... Second 'b1','b2','b3','X','b4' ..... I want to add X to the null position.

Answer (score -1):

you can use your foreach loop like:

```
foreach ($records as $key => $record) {
    if (isset($records[$key-1]) {
        $updateID = $records[$key-1];
        $this->Misc->update($updateID, $record['field'] );
    }
}
```

or the other way around:

```
foreach ($records as $key => $record) {
    if (isset($records[$key+1]) {
        $updateID = $records[$key+1];
        $this->Misc->update($updateID, $record['field'] );
    }
}
```